# Is there a standardized sitemap format?

Tags: java, xml, web-scraping, sitemap

I want to build a webscraper that scrapes a few websites sitemaps. I have come across this format a few times https://developer.mozilla.org/sitemap.xml. I'm wondering if this is the standard or if there is one.

If there isn't one what would be the best way for scraping sitemaps? A regex, or some library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use DOM API for this. And sitemap format explained there http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html

Answer (score 1):

If you use Java then [Java Sitemap Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sitemap-parser/) may help. Parsing sitemaps with PHP was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043654/parsing-an-xml-navigation-sitemap-with-php).